# How to find the last six rows(dynamic) sum of one column based on another column

Tags: mysql, sql

```
BallByBallID   Deliveries   RunsScored    BowlPlayerId        BatPlayerId

      109               0              1            127               4
      110             0.1              2            127               6
      111             0.2              3            127               6
      112             0.3              4            127               4
      113             0.4              6            127               4
      114             0.5              6            127               4
      230               0              1            162               4
      231             0.1              2            162               6
      232             0.2              3            162               6
      233             0.3              4            162               4
      234             0.4              5            162               4
      235             0.5              6            162               6
      236               1              1            169               4
      237             1.1              2            169               6
      238             1.2              3            169               6
      239             1.3              4            169               4
      240             1.4              5            169               4
      241             1.5              6            169               6
```

I have data in the above mentioned format. Now i want to find the **sum** of **RunsScored** and **BowlPlayerId** for last inserted data (the data is dynamic the last six may change at any time) **based** on **BallByBallId**.
I tried to find the solution by using like this.........

```
SELECT SUM(RunsScored) from (select BallByBallId from BallByBall ORDER BY BallByBallId DESC LIMIT 6);
```

It is giving total some......

```
SELECT SUM(RunsScored) from (SELECT top 6 * from BallByBall ORDER BY BallByBallId DESC) A GROUP BY A.BowlPlayerID
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT SUM(RunsScored+BowlPlayerID) 
  FROM from BallByBall group by BallByBallId limit 6;

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f3ab78/10

Comment: It is showing the error like.........................You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '6 SUM(RunsScored) FROM from BallByBall group by BallByBallId' at line 1

Comment: The same query i have tried what you mentioned..........it is showing the same error.......i am executing in **mysql query browser**...